# Get the all of loaded classes when application runtime

Tags: java, detach

I wanted write a simple program and get the all of classes loaded and calculate the size,anybody have ideas?
look forword your reply and answer,thank you very much.

Comment: `java -verbose:ClassName` command will give you the list of all loaded java classes.

Comment: no no,i means i wanted write a monitor program and get the other java application loaded classes and calculate the size.so the ClassName i can't known