# Spring2.x and Spring3.x maven dependency

Tags: spring, maven, conflict

i have a question about maven transitive dependency.

i have a project A and dependency the project b and spring 2.x but the project b dependency spring 3.x

you known the spring framework splited several modules.

so the problem as below.

if i exclusive the spring3.x dependency in project A i'm afraid the project can running because the project b need spring3.x api and project A dependency B

if i remove the spring2.x in project A ,i'm afraid the project A can't running too,maybe some old api be removed at spring3.x

anybody have some solutions for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

This is not a maven or spring issue - its more related to the design of your software. You need to make a decision which spring version you are going with. Usually upgrading spring is not the biggest mess, sometimes you need to change the set of dependencies as they move stuff around - but Google is quite helpful with this - or findjar.com.

I assume both A and B run in the same process (or classloader)? You are not deploying them separately? So you need to decide which spring version to use. If you can't change dependencies in project B use their spring version. If you can: take the newer one and upgrade spring in project B.

Maven sadly does not include a magic jar mechanism. If you need different versions of the same jar around something like OSGi might help - but thats a looooong shot. And a complicated one as well. And usually not necessary. Maven (as you have noticed) helps you to manage the dependencies. Which one to use is your choice to make.

Comment: ok thank you ,i planing upgrade the spring version at project A,and try to convince other people in out team. and i have another question if you known the answer you can give me some advise ,thank you very much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313592/get-the-all-of-loaded-classes-when-application-runtime